# How does patterns() function become available in django.conf.urls package?

Tags: python, django

For Django 1.3.1, where is the source code that makes it possible to do a `from django.conf.urls import patterns` ?

In the [Django 1.3.1 source code for the django.conf.urls package](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/conf/urls), `__init__.py` is empty, so there is no code or `__all__` variable.  The code for the `patterns()` function appears to be in `defaults.py` which does have an `__all__` variable.

How does Python end up including a `pattern()` function in the django.conf.urls package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem:

1. I discovered I was wrong about thinking I was successfully running 
   `from django.conf.urls import pattern` 
   in Django 1.3.1.  The code was actually 
   `from django.conf.urls.defaults import pattern`
2. There are two different Django tutorials:

   - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ - this is the one that shows up first in a google search for "django tutorial".  However, this is for the Django "dev" version, not for Django 1.3.1.  It uses 
     `from django.conf.urls import pattern`
   - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/ - this is the one for Django 1.3.1, and uses `from django.conf.urls.defaults import pattern`
3. I opened Django ticket 17770 for this, and it was closed as a duplicate of ticket 16932.  Ticket 16933 was opened and fixed to remedy the confusion of the different versions of documentation/tutorials.  However, it wasn't apparent to me.  I added a screenshot to 16933 showing how to see which version of the docs you are reading (and to select a different version).
   [image]
4. I was confused because I thought I was using 
   `from django.conf.urls import...`
    as the tutorial states, and I thought that code was working.  But in fact I was using the `urls.py` code that gets created with `django-admin.py startproject`, and this code is correctly using 
   `from django.conf.urls.defaults import...`
    for Django 1.3.1.  That worked.
5. My confusion surfaced in tutorial 4, when I copied the `polls/urls.py` code from the tutorial for the dev version.  That code is `from django.conf.urls import...` and it causes:

   > Django Version:    1.3.1
   >   Exception Type:    ImportError
   >   Exception Value:   cannot import name patterns
   >   Exception Location:    /.../django_tutorial_1/polls/urls.py in , line 1

jdi, thanks for your help.  Although your answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it encouraged me to keep going.  My question stated a false fact, which I later discovered (per #1 above).

Answer (score 1):

Its in the defaults module inside of the urls package.

```
>>> from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
>>> patterns
<function patterns at 0x102444410>
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/conf/urls/defaults.py

I realize that in the django docs they make a reference like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example

`from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include`

But (at least for me) it produces an error. It may have been included at that location at one point but the current source does not show it there any more. Every 1.3 project I have imports patterns() from the defaults module.

**Update**

The django dev branch docs refer to patterns as being under the urls package. But the stable 1.3 docs refer to it being under defaults.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

So I would say the stable way to access it is via default module. You were most likely at one point using the dev branch of django, because creating a new project with the stable 1.3 even defines its default urls.py with the defaults location

Comment: Yes, I see that patterns() can be imported via the django.conf.urls.defaults module.  But my question is how it's able to be imported from the django.conf.urls package.  I have 9 projects where I'm able to import it from django.conf.urls module.  Now I created a new project, following the Django tutorial, and I'm getting an "ImportError - cannot import name patterns".  I'm using the same virtualenv with the same Python and Django.  If I change it to django.conf.urls.defaults it does work, but I want to understand how django.conf.urls.patterns() works sometimes.